# Recursive unrar of several folders

Tags: script, nas, shell-script, rar

I have several RAR archives spread around multiple directories but all under a particular root folder on my Debian based NAS.
Could someone help me write a simple script that would recursively go into each folder, unrar the contents, go back to the parent folder and move onto the next directory?
So:

```
cd Photos/Summer/Italy/
unrar e Italy.rar
wait
cd ../France/
unrar e France.rar
wait
etc...
```

So just point it to root folder "Photos" and it blitzes through it unraring everything on the way...

Eg, directory structure:

```
*Photos:
 -Summer
  --Italy
   ---Italy.rar
   ---Italy.r01
   ---Italy.r02
  --France
   ---France.rar
   ---France.r01
   ---France.r02
 -Winter
  --Siberia
   ---Siberia.rar
   ---Siberia.r01
   ---Siberia.r02
  --Canada
   ---Snow.rar
   ---Snow.r01
   ---Snow.r02
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
find Photos/ -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar e {} \;
```

Comment: Brilliant, didn't know it was so easy!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to move the unrar'd photos to another destination, just enter the destination in the end, like this:

`find source_dir/ -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar e -o- {} /new/destination_dir/ \;`

Answer (score 6):

`unrar` has built-in recursion using the `-r` `Recurse subdirectories` switch.

`unrar x -r <parent directory>`
Extracts contents of all subdirectories under `<parent directory>` into each subdirectory, keeping any directory structure that exists in the `.rar` files. Use `e` instead of `x` if directory structure is unwanted.

Comment: This will extract the files from the subdirectory archives into `<parent directory>`.  It won't place the extracted files into the subdirectory next to the `.rar` files.  So it depends on what outcome is desired.  The OP wasn't specific in this case.  Sometimes your answer is useful to me but other times I need the `find` answer.

Comment: Didn't work on my Raspberry Pi. Used find instead.